# Using APT on Android Termux (terminal emulator) to install Ubuntu packages?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, android, desktop-environments

The Android termimal emulator, Termux, includes APT, but I am not able to install many packages with it. Mostly, I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package (name of packages)
```

I wonder if I can use termux or any other Android terminal to install packages and software, including a GUI, like with Ubuntu Server.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Although I do not think this will work due to differences in the standard linux kernel and the android kernel, you can definitely try it out. You have to first add a repository in order to be able to install packages.

Comment: Debian and Android are not compatible.

Comment: This belongs on [android.se] in my opinion

Comment: `apt list` will list all available packages

Answer (score 2):

No. Ubuntu (well, Debian really) packages are only for Debian based systems. The packages rely on core functionality of the underlying OS (ie Debian) to work correctly.

You may be able to hack a method to install them, but the vast majority (if not all) will simply not function.

Answer (score 1):

Try `apt search (package)` to search packages, because some packages are not available for Termux.
By the way, Android has no X support as default, so GUI packages won't work.